# Pandas: Create an output from multiple columns, some of which can have NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

[image: sample]

I would like to aggregate it by making an array out of the columns in a particular order, namely `invited_date` followed by `cancelled_date` followed by `attended_date`. I would also like to only include non-NaN values. So for the sampled data, this would produce:

```
[2015-05-30]
[2016-03-26]
[2016-03-25]
[2016-03-24]
[2016-03-02]
```

I would also like to produce an accompanying column that includes an array indicating per row which columns were not Nan and arranging those in a desired order. This would produce:

```
[invited_date]
[attended_date]
[attended_date]
[attended_date]
[attended_date]
```

In a sample row that looked like this:

```
2016-09-15, 2016-09-11, 2016-09-13
```

I would thus end up with two additional columns:

```
[2016-09-11, 2016-09-13, 2016-09-15], [invited_date, cancelled_date, attended_date]
```

How can I do this? I don't even know how to make a start.

Comment: Are you trying to produce two Nx1 arrays where N is the number of non-NaN cells in the dataframe?

Comment: Do you expect the output to be ordered by date somehow?